# Cant import Souceforge subversion project into Netbeans

Tags: svn, netbeans, sourceforge

I have been using Sourceforge with Subversion for some projects the last 6 months. A week ago I installed a new dual boot on my laptop (Linux Mint and Windows 7). I usually work my projects on both systems. I just tried to make a checkout to import a project A into Netbeans (my Netbeans version is the x64 java jdk 7 + netbeans) and the result was that Netbeans asked me if I wanted to create a new project with the existing sources. I clicked ok, but the new project was created without the content the repository has of the project. I am sure the repository is ok, I accessed it and it still has the code, but for some reason I cant import it into Netbeans.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of NetBeans are you using? Are you using Subversion from the OS, or a NetBeans plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was that my account logged off, so I was using the public link to my Sourceforge project to sync with Netbeans.